# Finding values of r based on given remainders of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

> Let $r$ be some real constant and $P(x)$ a polynomial which has remainder 2 when divided by $x-r$, and remainder $-2x^2-3x+4$ when divided by $(2x^2+7x-4)(x-r)$. Find all values of $r$.

I can't really organize a proper enough solution that isn't simply trial and error for this problem.

Can anyone show a systematic approach to this problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$P(x) = Q_1(x)(x-r)+2 = Q_2(x)(2x^2+7x-4)(x-r) -2x^2 -3x +4 $$

With $Q_1, Q_2$ being two polynomials. Then surely, when $x=r$, you have:

$$2  = -2r^2 -3r+4 \iff -2r^2 -3r+2=0$$

That should be easy to find which values $r$ can take by solving this equation.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $P(x)$ can be written as$$(2x^2+7x-4)(x-r)Q(x)-2x^2-3x+4.$$Therefore$$2=P(r)=-2r^2-3r+4.$$Therefore, $r=-2$ or $r=\frac12$. So, test these two values.